# How to display items of groups in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, grouping, angular-filters

I have items who are in groups.

WebAPI:

```
Add(new Name { group = "de", fname = "Hans" }); //germany
Add(new Name { group = "de", fname = "Peter" }); //germany
Add(new Name { group = "us", fname = "John" }); //usa
Add(new Name { group = "jpm", fname = "Chen" }); //japan
```

The service:

```
$scope.nameslist = personService.name.query();
```

The names are showing in a table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in filteredNames = (nameslist | filter:formGroup)">
   <td>{{ item.fname }}</td>
</tr>
```

The search form is in the same view of the table.

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">DE</label>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="checked" ng-click="chosenGroup()" ng-model="formGroup.checked" value="de" />
  </div>

  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">US</label>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="checked" ng-click="chosenGroup()" ng-model="formGroup.checked" value="us" />
  </div>

  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">JPN</label>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="checked" ng-click="chosenGroup()" ng-model="formGroup.checked" value="jpn" />
      </div>
</div>
```

How can I define the filter for the corresponding group?

Comment: You can use an object for the filter : in the DE radio input set ng-click="formGroup.group='de'".

Comment: @PierreMaoui thx for your comment. Only the german group works fine. But when I click on japan or us then I get a empty table.

Comment: Are you sure you had correctly adapted your code from jpn and us : ng-click="formGroup.group='jpn'" ng-click="formGroup.group='us'" ? I see 'jpm', not 'jpn', would it be the cause ?

Comment: @PierreMaoui Yes it is correctly written. Only 'de' works. No I've write jpm only here in the post wrong. US also doesn't work although I have defined `<input type="radio" class="radio" name="checked" ng-click="formGroup.group='us'" ng-model="formGroup.checked" value="us" />`

Comment: Could you try ng-change instead of ng-click ?

Comment: @PierreMaoui This is the same result. When I change the filter to `filter:formGroup.group` then I get almost the right result. It is showing the group value and the items who has the value 'us' in their name.

Comment: Ok, I guess I get it, can you replace  ng-model="formGroup.checked" by  ng-model="checked", it creates a conflict in your filter.

Comment: @PierreMaoui Thx that was the solution :)